# how to convert vtk polydata to voxel image using python and vtk package

Tags: python, image, visualization, vtk

I have a vtk polydata file(xml format, extension ".vtp"), it contains many meshes(Polys, Points, Cells). It's the annotation of 3-d image data. Now I want to convert it to 3-d voxel data, how can I do it with vtk and python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: vtkRessampleFilter

Comment: @MathieuWestphal Could you please add further details/info concerning the use of vtkRessampleFilter?  I'm facing the same problem (convert vtk polydata to 3d voxel coordinates using Python) and struggling to find a solution. I've done some research regarding vtkRessampleFilter but couldn't find anything helpful. Any clue that you can provide will be most appreciated.

Comment: https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkResampleWithDataSet.html